# Issue with Dynamic Sender Profile

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to create a dynamic sender profile in Salesforce Marketing Cloud. I have a fields first_Name in data extension which I want to use as from name. 
How can I do this?

I created a dynamic sender profile and used %%first_Name%% as from Name and %%ReplyEmailAddress%% as the from email.

what should I do to populate the Sender profile dynamically from the first_Name field?